# e-signature for SharePoint documents. What are my OTB options

Tags: document-library, third-party-software, digital-signature

I'm out looking or a way for users to be able to sign documents (word/pdf)when approving documents.
Are there ways to achieve this without third party tools like Adobe Sign, Docusign?
Any help or resources or hints would be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you check [Collect Signatures workflow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/all-about-collect-signatures-workflows-ee27dc94-8b8d-4d2b-898c-1754a397cb2b). does this helps?

Comment: Thanks Ganesh .but will this work with SharePoint online and i'm using power automate for approvals.
I can't see much about this anywhere

Answer (score 0):

As Ganesh already suggested, the only out-of-the-box way to collect signatures in SharePoint On-prem and Online is to use the [Collect Signatures workflow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/all-about-collect-signatures-workflows-ee27dc94-8b8d-4d2b-898c-1754a397cb2b). It's a Workflow 2010 engine and is no longer available in SharePoint Online. Also, it's not related to Power Automate.

There are no other free out-of-the-box options, unfortunately. However, you could instruct users to manually input a [signature into a signature line](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-a-signature-f3b3f74c-2355-4d53-be89-ae9c50022730). Quote:

> Use the Signature Line command to insert a signature line with an X by
> it to show where to sign a document.
>
> - Click where you want the line.
> - Click Insert > Signature Line.

[image]

> - Click Microsoft Office Signature Line.
> - In the Signature Setup box, you can type a name in the Suggested signerbox. You can also add a title in the Suggested signer’s title
>   box.
> - Click OK. The signature line appears in your document.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Denis.
Will try these options and see if it works